# Jersey 1.1.4 Errors

Tags: jersey

Have deployed HelloWorld Webservice using jersey.When the war is deployed in jboss 4.2.3 with jdk 1.5 get the below list of errors during startup.

**ERROR [STDERR] Apr 3, 2012 12:15:26 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init**
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
....
**ERROR [STDERR] Apr 3, 2012 12:15:26 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl initiate**

Tried formating the web.xml but it has not helped.
Do suggest what needs to be done to overcome this error in log.
The functionality works fine but the error is displayed

Comment: Publish `web.xml` and your Java controller: we will help you with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you've got a @Path annotated resource in your package, which you defined in your deployment descriptor? When yes, working with eclipse, for me it helped to clean the project or to clean the server.

Comment: Yes we do have a @Path annotated.Can you pls suggest how project clean helps ?

Comment: Link that was used to create the webservice http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/    but have used jersey1.1.4 and jdk 1.5